# How to reset a HTML Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this HTML

```
<select class="task" id="c1740778" name="c1740778" data-default-value="NotStarted">
<option value="NotStarted" selected="selected">NotStarted</option>
<option value="Complete">Complete</option>
</select>
```

and the following Javascript that is called when the select is changed

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save ?')) {
   console.log("complete changed");
} else {
   console.log("Reset");
}
```

How do I return the select to the original state if a user cancels?

I have tried

```
$(this).get(0).val("default-value");
```

but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `$(this).val($(this).data('default-value'));` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$(this).val("NotStarted");`

```js
$('#c1740778').change(function(){
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save ?')) {
   console.log("complete changed");
  } else {
     $(this).val("NotStarted");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="task" id="c1740778" name="c1740778" data-default-value="NotStarted">
<option value="NotStarted" selected="selected">NotStarted</option>
<option value="Complete">Complete</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could save the initial state as a variable when the page loads, and the set it to that when the user cancels:

```js
var taskInit = $('.task').val();
$('.task').on('change', function(){

  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save ?')) {
     console.log("complete changed");
  } else {
     console.log("Reset");
     $(this).val(taskInit);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="task" id="c1740778" name="c1740778" data-default-value="NotStarted">
<option value="NotStarted" selected="selected">NotStarted</option>
<option value="Complete">Complete</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set reset the value if user cancels the confirmation using

```
document.getElementById("c1740778").value = "NotStarted";
```

here is the demo

```js
function call(){
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save ?')) {
   console.log("complete changed");
} else {
   document.getElementById("c1740778").value = "NotStarted"
}
}
```

```html
<select class="task" id="c1740778" onchange="call()" name="c1740778" data-default-value="NotStarted">
<option value="NotStarted" selected="selected">NotStarted</option>
<option value="Complete">Complete</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

First answer already gives the idea. But, if you want to use your data attribute on the select element; you can use `$(el).data("attr-name")` method.

```js
function reset(){
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save ?')) {
      console.log("complete changed");
  } else {
      $("#c1740778").val($("#c1740778").data("default-value"));
      console.log("Reset");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="task" id="c1740778" name="c1740778" data-default-value="NotStarted">
<option value="NotStarted" selected="selected">NotStarted</option>
<option value="Complete">Complete</option>
</select>


<span onClick="reset()">TestMe</span>
```